# Initialize windows form object dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I **dynamically initialize a win form.** In my application I am having numerous forms, like more than 50 and the below code is repeated as many times..

so I want to create some function for it and do this job. But how can I create a `new () instance` of a particular Form.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
private void ShowForm(object frm)
{
    if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed)
    {
        frm = new <<Here is some Class Name>> { MdiParent = this };
        frm.Show();
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
    else
    {
        frm.Activate();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Well how are you trying to decide which form to use?

Comment: Can I pass the type for it and decide?

Comment: Sure. So you have a `Type` object for it?

Comment: Type t=new Type(typeOf(MyForm));
Can I use this and pass it in my function?

Comment: You don't need `new Type()` here - just `typeof(MyForm)`. But if you know it at compile-time, you could use generics instead.

Comment: what is `object frm`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the `Type` to use, you can use `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
private void ShowForm(Form form, Type type)
{
    if (form == null || form.IsDisposed)
    {
        form = (Form) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        form.MdiParent = this;
        form.Show();
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
    else
    {
        form.Activate();
    }
}
```

Or if you're calling it from different places and know at *compile-time* which type to use:

```
private void ShowForm<T>(T form) where T : Form, new()
{
    if (form == null || form.IsDisposed)
    {
        form = new T();
        form.MdiParent = this;
        form.Show();
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
    else
    {
        form.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks Jon Skeet. This was helpful.

Comment: Grrrr! Why are we always behind you Jon?

Comment: I recommend this generic solution.

Comment: And also a very good explanation and code samples. Definitely this was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection.

[Activator.CreateInstance - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

```
        frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t) // t is a type parameter
```

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks Tilak. This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Activator:

```
var form = System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(yourclassname)), null) as Form;
form.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of generics:

```
    private void ShowForm<T>(T frm) where T : Form
    {
        if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed)
        {
            frm = new T { MdiParent = this };
            frm.Show();
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            frm.Activate();
        }
    }
```